# Maven Eclipse Java Error: "The import com.binance4j.binance cannot be resolved"

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, dependencies

I have set up a new project, converted it to a maven project and have imported the necessary dependencies. Independent from what dependency I use, I always get error message "The import ... cannot be resolved".

Things I have done so far:
-Rebuilt and saved the project
-Checked if Maven Repository contains files: it does (see screenshot)

[image]

-Downloaded the maven to eclipse plugin from [github](https://github.com/eclipse-m2e/m2e-core/blob/master/README.md#-installation)
-tried it with different JRE Versions (JavaSE-1.6 and JavaSE-15)

My pom.xml contains:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>BuyCoinDieZweite</groupId>
  <artifactId>BuyCoinDieZweite</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <dependencies>
      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.binance4j/binance4j-spot -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.binance4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>binance4j-spot</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.12</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>


  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <release>17</release>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

My Main java file for test purpose:

```
import com.binance4j.binance.SpotApiRestClient;
import com.binance4j.model.market.TickerPrice;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    @Test
    public void testConnection() {
        // Create a client with API Key and Secret Key
        // Replace "yourApiKey" and "yourSecretKey" with your actual keys
        SpotApiRestClient client = new SpotApiRestClient("yourApiKey", "yourSecretKey");

        // Get ticker price for BTC/USDT
        TickerPrice tickerPrice = client.getTickerPrice("BTCUSDT");

        // Check that the ticker price is not null
        Assert.assertNotNull(tickerPrice);
        
        // Check that the symbol is as expected
        Assert.assertEquals("BTCUSDT", tickerPrice.getSymbol());
    }
}
```

There are no errors in the pom.xml, but only in the Main.java file. See the following (I have left out the errors "ObjectXYZ cannot be resolved":

```
"The import com.binance4j.binance cannot be resolved"
"The import com.binance4j.model.market.TickerPrice cannot be resolved"
"The import org.junit.Assert cannot be resolved"
"The import org.junit.Test cannot be resolved"
```

Comment: In your screenshot, I see `junit-4.12.jar` of test scope (shown with a darker icon) which contains `org.junit.Assert` and `org.junit.Test`, so it is not available in your non-test source folder `src`. The JARs are collapsed, not showing where `com.binance4j.binance` and `com.binance4j.model.market.TickerPrice` is contained.

Comment: First why have you changed the default `<sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>` if don't know what you are doing... second remove that line... and to solve your problem you have to add appropriate dependencies for the libraries you are using... Furthermore you have to use at least JDK 17 because you have defined `<release>17</release>` ... and also correctly locate your files for production code into `src/main/java/<package>` and for test into `src/test/java/<package>`...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried updating the maven project to download the dependencies?

[image: E]

UPDATED!

You can't find the junit imports because the scope is "test". Here you can see how the same class in /src/main/java does not find dependencies, but in /src/test/java it can import the Test and Assert classes.

Check the other two classes, they don't exist in the libraries you are importing. I don't know those libraries but in all maven central com.binance4j* dependencies neither of these two classes exist.

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: Hi, thank you. Yes, I have tried that, without seeing any changes.